# What kind of phrase/clause is "as far as I know"?

Tags: phrases, clauses

I would like to know what kind of phrase/clause "as far as I know" is, and why.

Comment: Do you mean what it's called grammatically? Your question could also be answered by "English", "clichéd", "five-word" and so on.

Comment: Great question (and answers!), strange that it's closed.  I've proposed an edit adding the word "grammatically" although the question seems quite clear to me without it.  @PeterShor: seriously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an [adverbial clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause), which is also a dependent or subordinate clause.

Comment: What you say makes sense. I found an explanation that agrees with your answer: http://www.italki.com/answers/question/84831.htm

Comment: Do you know what kind of adverbial clause it is?

Comment: I would probably call it a conditional clause, since it expresses the possibility of doubt. It's another way of saying "If I'm right about this, [main clause]."

Answer (score 2):

In 'Non-assertive  Epistemic Adverbs and Deontic Necessity' at http://semanticsarchive.net/Archive/jE2MDk3O/ESSLLI03_paper.pdf   Demet Corcue writes:

Epistemic modal adverbs such as *perhaps, maybe, certainly, sure, surely* etc. are analyzed under the label of *discourse markers*.

His definition of discourse markers would certainly include the clause *as far as I know*.

I am one of those who thinks that the traditional label 'sentence adverbial' is a misnomer, and would class both *perhaps* and *as far as I know as* (single- or multi-word) *pragmatic markers subclass modality*.

Pragmatic markers fall outside the 'central identity' of the matrix sentence:

1. syntactically: they are parenthetical (a grammatical sentence will be left if they are omitted)
2. semantically: they do not form a **direct** part of the statement in the matrix sentence.

They are used to facilitate conversation, structure discourse, or, as here, to add a comment to the base sentence. 'As far as I know' adds a comment relating to the reliability ('truth value') of the statement in the sentence proper, and hence is a modal pragmatic marker.